# CSS Help, Making Menu Fluid

Tags: css, menu, stylesheet, fluid, liquid-layout

I got some help with this menu earlier but have a different request now.

The menu works fine with fixed width but I would like the words to wrap ONLY on the top menu categories. I need to be able to have n categories and have the width be evenly distributed. Obviously n would be within reason (I am not going to have 50 categories) but I  need to be able to add more and not worry about hitting my width limit.

Thanks for any help.

Link:

http://www.seth-duncan.com/Test/TestMenu.html

-Seth

Comment: I hopped in to check it out but you've got your wrapping div style's declared inline.  I makes it difficult to work with, why not define that in the stylesheet?

Comment: Yeah it was just a temporary in-line fix to wrap it while I was testing. The stylings are done in the real stylesheet but had to add a wrapping div for the test version. Any ideas to have the text wrap ?

Answer (score 2):

For every top level menu item add the class 'heading' (or something similar).

Then add the following CSS to your page:

```
#menu li
{
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#menu .heading
{
    white-space: normal;
}
```