# CSS: Dynamic width on Menu

Tags: css, menu, stylesheet, liquid-layout

#### Exact Duplicate of

> [CSS Help, Making Menu Fluid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994208/css-help-making-menu-fluid)

The menu works fine with fixed width but I would like the words to wrap ONLY on the top menu categories. I need to be able to have n categories and have the width be evenly distributed. Obviously n would be within reason (I am not going to have 50 categories) but I need to be able to add more and not worry about hitting my width limit.

Thanks for any help.

Link:

http://www.seth-duncan.com/Test/TestMenu.html

Comment: exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994208/css-help-making-menu-fluid

Answer (score 2):

> and have the width be evenly distributed

Only tables (or CSS display:table) will give you this behaviour unless you calculate widths with JS (not easy or ideal).